# How to integrate Cppcheck in MPLAB X 6.0 or NetBeans IDE?

Tags: netbeans, pic, microchip, mplab, cppcheck

Microchip added a MISRA check function in MPLAB X 5.45 which is just a plugin for the free Cppcheck and for me it works pretty well. In the further versions of MPLAP X the MISRA check was gone.
In MPLAB X 6.0 it was reintroduced, but requires a 499 $ license to use it in combination with a code coverage tool.
Is there any plugin to integrate just Cppcheck in MPLAB X or NetBeans?